# Simplify SQL query with multiple Sub-Selects

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-performance

### Goal

I would like to simplify the following sql query in term of visual length (decrease amount nested sub-selects) and/or performance and/or readability. This query is dedicated for MS Access, that's why there are parenthesis around `INNER JOIN`.

### Explanation

- To not lose global view all table relations are shortened after `ON` clauses.
- Table S1 and S2 is the same table S. To work, the query (MS Access to be precise) needed to separate names of S in different sub-selects.
- Level 1 query (T1) calculates: qty of defects, qty of production and defect rate in PPM for all production areas and subareas in specific period of time.
- Level 2 query (T2) calculates sum of defect rates from in T1 per area and adds some additional information like specific one main user from many attached to areas, area name itself and target taken for specific year and month.
- Level 3 query takes all from level 2 and adds some comment defined for specific year and week and also filter all the list down to areas where sum of defect rates exceeds target.

This query works as expected and all the columns in the result table show properlly calculated values and fields.

Is it possible to simplify this query?

### Note

I added sql-server tag to reach more pro-users. Sorry if it doesn't fit.

### Query

```
SELECT s1id, s2name, user, target, ratio, C.msg AS msg
FROM 

(SELECT s1id, S2.nam AS s2name, (U.lastname & ' ' & U.firstname) AS user, T.m1 AS target, SUM(ratio1) as ratio
FROM ((((

(SELECT S1.id AS s1id, WG.id AS wgid, SUM(IIF(D.ok=False,F.qty,0)) AS nok, SUM(F.qty) AS production, IIF(production > 0, CLNG(nok/production * 1000000), 0) AS ratio1 
FROM (((F
INNER JOIN D ON D.x = F.x)
INNER JOIN W ON W.x = D.x)
INNER JOIN WG ON WG.x = W.x)
INNER JOIN S1 ON S1.x = WG.x
WHERE F.entrydate BETWEEN #2017-01-23# And #2017-01-29#
GROUP BY S1.id, WG.id) AS T1

INNER JOIN S2 ON S2.x = T1.x)
INNER JOIN UPS ON UPS.x = S2.x)
INNER JOIN UP ON UP.x = UPS.x)
INNER JOIN U ON U.x = UP.x)
INNER JOIN T ON T.x = S2.x
WHERE UPS.main = true AND UP.positionid = 3 AND T.y = 2017 
GROUP BY sectorid, S2.nam, U.lastname, U.firstname, T.m1) AS T2

INNER JOIN C ON C.x = T2.x
WHERE C.yearnum = 2017 AND C.weeknum = 4 AND ratio > target
```

Comment: Are your table names really this cryptic?

Comment: Of course not. I simplified everything what was possible to do. I also wanted to _hide_ table names as it is not relevent for my question. Beside I still think that just letters are enough to see global view on this 3-level query. It looks also cleaner.

Comment: If you really need just assume that T = Targets, U = Users, UP = UserPositions, UPS = UserPositionSectors, S = Sectors, W = Workstations, D = Defects, C = Comments, F = MainTableWithValues etc...

Comment: I forgot how strange the automated queries are in Access. I would probably start a new query and put this together from scratch. As you said this is incredibly confusing like this.

Comment: This query was written by me from scratch. I didn't use any help from wizard of any kind. In fact due to some restrictions in company some people have to use MS Access database as backend. So I use this database as single file serveless one. I think query is written is correctly - it works - I just wonder if it can be written simpler or can be quicker.

Comment: Last comment from me. For my point of view it's hard to simplify it as each level of query ends with `GROUP BY` so it is closed part and next higher level just use lower level query as newly-created table. Personally I don't see here area for optimize it.